# R after replacing read.csv with fread incorrect number of dimensions error appears

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I was loading my csv file with plain:

```
baseData <- read.csv(datafile)
```

but as I want to load larger dataset I have moved to [data.table package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)

```
baseData <- fread(input = paste("zcat < ", datafile, sep=""))
```

all seems to work fine, and the data loads much faster, but when I hit the following line:

```
d <- baseData[baseData$some_prop==0,]
d <- d[!is.na(d[,"col"]) & (d[,"col"] == 0 | d[,"col"] == 1),]
```

I get error for `incorrect number of dimensions`

when using `read.csv` all is working fine.
Any idea what can get wrong ?

Comment: If dvName is your column then it should be in quotes d[,"dvName"]

Comment: thanks @Arunkumarmahesh, but it was a variable - I edited the question.

Comment: Convert col into numeric and try once hope it might work

Comment: thanks @Arunkumarmahesh, but the content of the column in already numeric. or you mean to something else?

Comment: You're working with a data.table after loading with fread, the subsetting is a little different

Comment: @Tensibai - interesting! how would you suggest me to change the code to comply with the new subsetting?

Comment: Sorry I did hit enter before the end of comment, if you want ot keep your old code you can setDF(d) before, or you'll have to remove the quotes around the column names IIRC (testing as soon as my R session gets back).

Comment: `fread` has a `data.table` argument which you can set to `FALSE` so you get a `data.frame` instead of a `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a data.table  the `j` part of the subsetting is meant to return a new value and the columns names should not be quoted or you'll get back exactly this value.

Example:

```
>d<-data.table(A=1:5,B=5:10)
> d[,A]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1
> d[,B]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
> d[,"B"]
[1] "B"
```

So for you particular case, removing the quotes around the columns names should fix the error.

If your code is quite long and use `data.frame` methods, you can use `setDF(d)` to make it work as-is before refactoring it.

To be complete, the error arise because your logical statement is of length 1 (`"col" == whatever` does just return one value `TRUE` or `FALSE`), not matching the number of rows of your data.table object.

Comment: thanks! I think I'm much closer now! after testing stuff out I have encountered the following line: d <- d[,colSums(is.na(d))<nrow(d)] that returns a logical instead of dataframe.. and that seems to be the source of all evil

Comment: @GuyDubrovski Probably, data.tables have a nice feature to update themselves in place by reference, so when you do this kind of reallocation as in data.frame, it turns bad :)

Comment: I have also tried to use setDT(d) before all manipulations in order ro prevent refactoring, but unfortunately the same happend :/

Comment: @GuyDubrovski `setDF` not `setDT`, the idea is to convert the dataset to data.frame again.

Comment: You are amazing! converting back to data.frame worked as magic! :) thanks!!

Comment: @GuyDubrovski I still recommend you to dig into data.table and review your actual code, you'll probably speed it up drastically by taking advantage of data.table update by reference

Comment: The behavior for `DT[, "B"]` changed with today's release of 1.9.8, item 3 in its changelog/NEWS: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md